# When do I use a task vs a DAG?

Tags: airflow

I'm struggling to understand the difference between a task and a DAG and when to use one over the other. I know a task is more granular and called within a DAG, but so much of Airflow documentation mentions creating DAGs on the go or calling other DAGs instead of tasks. Is there any significant difference between using either of these two options?

Answer (score 0):

A DAG is a collection of tasks with schedule information. Each task can perform different work based on our requirement. Let us consider below DAG code as an example. In the below code we are printing current time and then sending an e-mail notification after that.

```
#importing operators and modules
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator ##to call a python object
from airflow.operators.email_operator import EmailOperator ##to send email
from datetime import datetime,timedelta,timezone ##to play with date and time
import dateutil

#setting default arguments
default_args = {
    'owner': 'test dag',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2021, 1, 1),
    'email': ['myemailid@example.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 0
}

def print_time(**context):
    now_utc = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
    print("current time",now_utc)


with DAG('example_dag', schedule_interval='* 12 * * *', max_active_runs=1, catchup=False,default_args=default_args) as dag: ##dag name is 'example_dag'

    current_time = PythonOperator(task_id='current_time', python_callable=print_time,
                                    provide_context=True,
                                    dag=dag) ##task to call print_time definition

    send_email = EmailOperator(task_id='send_email', to='myemailid@example.com',
                                      subject='DAG completed successfully',
                                      html_content="<p>Hi,<br><br>example DAG completed successfully<br>", dag=dag) ## task to send email

    current_time >> send_email ##defining tasks dependency
```

Here current_time and send_email are 2 different tasks performing different work. Now we have a dependency here like we have to send an email once the current time is printed so we have established that task dependency at the end. Also we have given a scheduled_interval to run the DAG everyday at 12 PM. This together forms a DAG.